# cudaMallocManaged sometimes returns null pointer?

Tags: cuda

Why does CUDA's cudaMallocManaged function *sometimes* return a null pointer? I understand that on older architecture it isn't supported and returns a null pointer in that case, but I have a strange situation where it works sometimes but not others:

```
int main()
{
    const int n = pow(10, 5);
    int blockSize = 256;
    int N_blocks = (n + blockSize - 1)/blockSize;
    double *val;

    cudaMallocManaged(&val, n*sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        val[i] = 0;
    }

    r_line<<<N_blocks, blockSize>>>(n, val);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

works fine, and r_line returns the expected value. If I then add this to the main function

```
    double *rng_test_array;
    const int n_rng = 10;
    cudaMallocManaged(&rng_test_array, n_rng*sizeof(double));
    if (rng_test_array == nullptr)
    {
        printf("Null pointer \n");
        return 1;
    }
    cudaFree(val);
    cudaFree(rng_test_array);
}
```

and running it shows that the second call to cudaMallocManaged returns a null pointer. Removing the if statement, and attempting to perform any operations on the rng_test_array causes a segfault, as you'd expect. Why does this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code, I suggest using proper CUDA error checking, and run your code with `cuda-memcheck`.  Since you haven't provided a complete code, it's impossible to answer your question authoritatively.   However one possible scenario would be if your `r_line` kernel (which you haven't shown) is doing an illegal operation that is caught by the CUDA runtime. For example an egregious out-of-bounds access. Such an event would corrupt the CUDA context, and no further CUDA activity (CUDA API calls) would work.  In that case, `cudaMallocManaged` would report an error

Comment: In my view, your question fits category 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  In that case you are supposed to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Robert Crovella's comment was correct; using cuda-memcheck identified the issue in the r_line kernel, which was causing issues further down the line.